# Combo Box Access 2007 VB code

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6

How do you display combo box using recordset? Neither code piece given below is working. Neither rowsource nor additem is working. Editing the rowsource property in design view properties is not allowed, so I need to manually code it.

```
Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From studentInformation")

Do While Not MyRec.EOF
   comboBox.RowSource = MyRec![studentName]  'This code is not displaying anything...
   MyRec.MoveNext 
Loop
```

Or this code doesn't display anything

```
Set MyDB = CurrentDb

Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From studentInformation")

Do While Not MyRec.EOF
  tQue = MyRec![studentName]
  Combo7.AddItem(tQue)
  MyRec.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Combo7.AddItem(MyRec.Fields("studentName").Value) should work. Is the DO-While executed or no records fetched in MyRec ?

Comment: Do while executed sir to fetch MyRec until all data is fetched

Comment: @rags i tried to insert your suggested code, but it's still not displaying anything... still empty combo box...

Comment: @rags the table name is studentInformation, studentName contains example John, David, Paul

I'm trying to get the logic so i can understand and use it. i'm wondering why it's not working, is it because of the rowsource property? it's not coded manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you do in VB6 .. try this

```
Do While Not MyRec.EOF      
  Combo7.AddItem  MyRec.Fields.Item("studentName")
  MyRec.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: it's still not displaying anything... my sql query, i'm using VB in access, i'm not allowed to edit rowsource property in design view, i am required to manually code it, i wonder if it lacks the rowsource coding, but i did try to include rowsource, i'm not sure if it's the proper syntax because it's not displaying anything :(

Comment: sure thank you @matzon . i can't figure out what's wrong i tried a lot of methods already.
http://pastebin.com/pEvUcFiB

Comment: @user2490641 .. not only code .. I need it all with your DB ( with data tester only ) .. because I don't know what really occured in this ? .. if you dont mind ..